# Как посмотреть отзывы о заведении через "API поиск по организациям"?

Tags: yandex-places-api

Хотел бы узнать , возможно ли вообще посмотреть отзывы об организации через "API поиск по организациям". Если же нет , то как можно было бы реализовать переход на какую-нибудь организацию в яндекс картах или гугл картах (когда я получаю координаты, адрес и название организации)? Пытался создать ссылку запроса для гугл или яндекс карт, но как-то не вышло совсем. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

API Яндекс.Карт не даёт возмжоности получить отзывы. Недавно они только [виджет для отзывов](https://yandex.ru/blog/mapsapi/vidzhet-otzyvov-dobavte-otzyvy-s-yandeks-kart-na-svoy-sayt?from=club) организовали и возможносить [получать организации в виде геообъекта](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/findOrganization-docpage/), тогда вам будет и метка с координатами и название и прочие данные.

API ППО вообще не те задачи решает, он только для поиска организаций.